# Meteor generate dev bundle on Arm(raspberry pi)

Tags: meteor, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

ive updated all the necessary files so that the dev bundle script starts building.
my issue occurs when it starts to install all the nodejs modules. i've tried node 10.43 10.40 and the also the latest. ive seen other modified scripts that work but none have the most up to date meteor. any one have any ideas on what to do or what version of node i should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what you try to do with meteor but we have just updated our meteor universal for to the current stable 1.3.3.1 release.

If you check the README you will find also the guide "how to build your own". Take a look at the commits to the release-1.3.3.1-universal branch. Since we started there are a number of changes already established to run meteor on ARM.

Maybe you give it a try, the quick installation will load pre-built binaries for your easyness.

Cheers
Tom

Link: https://github.com/4commerce-technologies-AG/meteor

Comment: This is greta thanks for updating it! However the tinkerer in me still wants to figure out why I can't get the npm to install the packages without fail

Comment: @cronicryo what exactly do you try to run and what release of meteor are you using? I guess we are talking about `generate-dev-bundle.sh'? You should read the parts of "SLOW START" in the README as well as [this blog entry](https://meteor-universal.tumblr.com/post/132266856859/1st-time-installation-meteor-12x-universal-raspbian).

Comment: Im running it from the latest get from meteor with modifications to the files for arm support. It fails when it gets up to npm installing dev-bundle-tool-package.js

Comment: Just [check our commits for 1.3.3.1-universal](https://github.com/4commerce-technologies-AG/meteor/commits/release-1.3.3.1-universal) to see what has to be changed to get it run. Just make sure to see also the additional repos from our github for that task like (node, mongo, fibers, node-gyp). Happy coding :-)

Comment: Here is the [complete compare of the original 1.3.3.1 and the universal release](https://github.com/4commerce-technologies-AG/meteor/compare/4commerce-technologies-AG:release-1.3.3.1...release-1.3.3.1-universal)